# Is it ideal to receive response in JSON-stringified format on the frontend

Tags: javascript, json, v8

As per this [study](https://v8.dev/blog/cost-of-javascript-2019#json), JSON can be parsed more efficiently than JavaScript object literal. So, is it ideal to receive responses from APIs in JSON-stringified format? I believe, it should then be faster to parse than getting a response in JSON format.

If a response of an API is a `stringified JSON` it should be faster to parse/iterate than a response which is in `JSON` format.

Comment: The study is comparing *inline* JS object initialisers with JSON parsing *inline* string literals. It has nothing to do with fetching the response from an API.

Comment: What is *ideal* depends on the specific circumstances. Sometimes it is better for an API to return XML, sometimes JSON, sometimes plain text, sometimes an image, sometimes something else.

Answer (score 1):

> faster to parse

Faster than what? Please specify which two scenarios exactly you are comparing.

One thing I can say with certainty is that `JSON.parse(xhr_response_text)` is faster (and safer!) than `eval(xhr_response_text)`, when `xhr_response_text` is something like `'{"data": [{"foo": 1, "bar": 2}, {"foo": 42, "bar": 23}]}'`.

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty sure you are already sending a JSON string via HTTP to the frontend. It's just automatically parsed. The study you where referencing is about JSON parsing VS JS sourcecode parsing. But your API response would (idealy) never be touched by a JS parser anyways.